# SwiftUI move list cells and populate order in CoreData database

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftui-list

I have a problem with moving cells and save the order in CoreData database. I've got the move from UI perspective working, but I can't understand how to mirror it in the core data. Moved list entities have orderPriority attribute in CoreData, its an Int I would like to change on move action.

Move method attached to the list is this:

```
func move(from source: IndexSet, to destination: Int)
```

It seems like source and destination are two different things, for example
moving first cell to third position gives source=0 and destination=3, but
moving third cell to first position gives source=2 and destination=0, with only 3 elements in the array destination makes no sense to me.

Source looks like array index, but destination is what I can't undersand and this is why I can't change core data entities to respective order.

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ... but moving third cell to first position gives source=2 and destination=0, with only 3 elements in the array destination makes no sense to me.

Array indices start at zero, *source=2* is the 3rd element and *destination=0* is the 1st element. Index 2 becomes 0, index 0 becomes 1 and index 1 becomes 2.

By the way the type of source is `IndexSet`, you can move multiple items at non-subsequent indices to the *destination* index.

Per default Core Data records are unordered. If you have an index attribute in the entity you have to re-index the records, at least from the first index which has been changed.

Comment: You did point out a flaw and I decided to create an actual array from core data entities which then I applied native swift move function and by entity IDs then changed order in the database. I did understand the second example I'd given, but why destination=3 in the first example?

Comment: `destination=3` is the index **after** the last item, `destination=2` is the index **before** the last item. Imagine an empty array, there's only one insertion index available, index 0.

Comment: Greatly appreciated, I understand now!